# Why is Pandas to_datetime slower and shows higher peak memory usage with explicit format argument?

Tags: python, pandas

When trying to convert a column in a Pandas dataframe from string `'%Y%m%d'` to datetime, I noticed a wierd behavior where the code is slower and shows a much higher peak memory usage when `format` is explicitly set.

Example dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

# Example dataframe with a column formatted as '%Y%m%d'
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(start='2000-01-01', end='2023-01-01')})
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

- Compare time:

```
## Option 1: convert the column without explicit format
%timeit -n 500 pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
## 1.35 ms ± 143 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 500 loops each)


## Option 2: convert the column with specific format
%timeit -n 500 pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d')
## 5.32 ms ± 166 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 500 loops each)
```

- Compare peak memory usage:

```
import tracemalloc

tracemalloc.start()

## Option 1: convert the column without explicit format
pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
_, peak = tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()
print(f'Peak memory usage: {peak}')
tracemalloc.clear_traces()
## Peak memory usage: 141349


## Option 2: convert the column with specific format
pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d')
_, peak = tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()
print(f'Peak memory usage: {peak}')
tracemalloc.clear_traces()
## Peak memory usage: 1386294
```

Even more surprisingly, when I passed a wrong format `pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')`, the code ran successfully and the performance was similar to when format was not explicitly set.

The results are obtained with Pandas 1.4.3. I'm also seeing similar behavior with Pandas 1.3.4. Appreciate any help to understand why this is happening.